# How to get string as return value from function in C?

Tags: c

I am a newbie in C and am trying to make a hangman game where a player will have to guess a random word selected by the program. But I am stuck in getting the word. I tried a lot and found some answers on SO but could not relate it to my case.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

char dictionary[3][15] = {"food","cat","coder"};
//15 is max length of each word

char getWord() {
    srand(time(0));
    char *random_elem = dictionary[rand()%3];
    printf(random_elem);
    return random_elem;
}


void gamePlay() {
    *word = getWord();
    printf(*word);
    return;
}

int main() {

    printf("Welcome to Hangman\n");
    printf("------------------------------------\n\n");

    gamePlay();
}
```

The `printf` in the `getWord()` works but not in `gamePlay()`

The following error is generated:

```
<stdin>:11:12: warning: format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure) [-Wformat-security]
    printf(random_elem);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~
<stdin>:11:12: note: treat the string as an argument to avoid this
    printf(random_elem);
           ^
           "%s", 
<stdin>:12:12: error: cannot initialize return object of type 'char' with an lvalue of type 'char *'
    return random_elem;
           ^~~~~~~~~~~
<stdin>:17:6: error: use of undeclared identifier 'word'; did you mean 'for'?
    *word = getWord();
     ^~~~
     for
<stdin>:17:6: error: expected expression
<stdin>:18:13: error: use of undeclared identifier 'word'
    printf(*word);
            ^
1 warning and 4 errors generated.
```

OS: Android 11
App: Cxxdroid

*If that might help*

Comment: `getWord` returns a `char *`, not a `char`. Moreover, where is `word` defined?

Comment: Then how shoud i write it?

Comment: I see...thank u so much...helped a lot :,-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right code is the above.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

char dictionary[3][15] = {"food","cat","coder"};
//15 is max length of each word

char* getWord() {
    srand(time(0));
    char *random_elem = dictionary[rand()%3];
    printf("%s\n",random_elem);
    return random_elem;
}


void gamePlay() {
    char *word = getWord();
    printf("%s\n",word);
    return;
}

int main() {

    printf("Welcome to Hangman\n");
    printf("------------------------------------\n\n");

    gamePlay();
}
```

Comment: Will you please explain how char* and *word solved the issue?

Comment: Char is a  character. char* is a string and you havent declared the type of variable word which is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can return a pointer, since the actual strings are declared with static storage duration (if they are local variables, you can't do that). You should however const-qualify the pointer since string literals are read-only. Fixed code:

```
const char* getWord() {
    static const char dictionary[3][15] = {"food","cat","coder"};
 
    srand(time(0));
    const char *random_elem = dictionary[rand()%3];
    puts(random_elem);
    return random_elem;
}
```

I moved the variable declarations inside the function since global variables should be avoided. `static` ensures that they still have static storage duration so you can return a pointer to them.

The warnings about "format string is not a string literal" is nothing to be concerned with in this case. If you replace `printf` with `puts` they should go away.

Comment: puts helps a lot but and your code solved most of the errors but still the printf i wanted did not work